# Dompdf Arabic Support

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using Dompdf to convert html to pdf.

Here's the code:

```
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
$tmp = sys_get_temp_dir();

$dompdf = new Dompdf([
   'logOutputFile' => '',
    // authorize DomPdf to download fonts and other Internet assets
    'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
    // all directories must exist and not end with /
    'fontDir' => $tmp,
    'fontCache' => $tmp,
    'tempDir' => $tmp,
    'chroot' => $tmp,
 ]);

$html = // Html code here

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("fitphase",array("Attachment"=>0));
```

I have used the following font:

```
<style>
* { 
   font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Now, issue is that the text displayed in arabic is showing from left to right and I want the direction to be from right to left.

I have found this link https://github.com/learn05/arabiclang/ for Laravel but need the solution with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this link [arabic fonts display in reverse order in dompdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201257/arabic-fonts-display-in-reverse-order-in-dompdf)

Add the below code in the vendor/dompdf/dompdf/Renderer/Text.php

```
if (strtolower($style->direction) == 'rtl') {
  preg_match_all('/./us', $text, $ar);
  $text = join('',array_reverse($ar[0]));
}
```

Put above this line in Text.php

> $this->_canvas->text($x, $y, $text,$font, $size,$style->color, $word_spacing, $letter_spacing);

Add the style where one wants to see the result

```
p {
direction: rtl;
text-align: right;
}
```